# Do I need to use std::atomic_ when having one reader and one writer thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11, shared-ptr, stdatomic

I am looking to use std::shared_ptr in a reader/writer scenario. One thread constantly receives new information and keeps a smart pointer to the latest data. When the time comes to run my slow calc I take a smart pointer to all the data to ensure that I am looking at consistent data. In the example below when I use a and then b I know that they belong together.

I am not sure if I should use atomic_load and atomic_store here? I don't care to much which version of Foo I am looking at as long as it is consistent and valid.

So should I use atomic here on my smart pointers in order for this code to work from two different threads?

Thanks,

Paul

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


class Foo{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
};

class MyClass{
public:
  std::shared_ptr <Foo> lastValue;
  void realTimeUpdate (Foo* latest) { //takes ownership of Foo
      lastValue=std::shared_ptr <Foo> (latest); //Is this OK to do without using std::atomic_?
  };

  void doSlowCalcFromAnotherThread () {
      //take a reference to all input data
      std::shared_ptr <Foo> stableValue=lastValue; //Is this OK to do without using std::atomic_
      //display a and b guaranteed that they come from the same message
      std::cout<<"a: "<<stableValue->a<<std::endl;
      std::cout<<"b: "<<stableValue->b<<std::endl;
  };
};
```

Comment: You should probably use a `std::mutex` to guard access to the pointer, and call it a day. The assignment to `std::shared_ptr` is not atomic.

Answer (score 2):

1. shared_ptr::operator= is not atomic by default.
2. shared_ptr is not TriviallyCopyable, so it cannot be template parameter to std::atomic.

So you have to synchronize 'em in some other way, e.g. via std::mutex.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to use `std::atomic_load()` and `std::atomic_store()` overloaded in the `memory` header for `std::shared_ptr` arguments. Otherwise, you would have a data race in the code. (I assume that you have a C++11 compliant compiler according the question's tags.)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it looks like gcc 4.9.2 does not implement the std::atomic_load and store for std::shared_ptr so I have to stick with the mutex. C++17 might include an std::atomic_shared_ptr that should work in these cases but that will be a while before that is available.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any communication between two threads must be protected in some manner. The issue in this case is that `std::shared_ptr<>::operator=` is not guaranteed to be atomic and thus may invoke undefined behavior if both threads are accessing it

Comment: I was hoping to use something like http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic

Comment: If you have a c++11 compiler then you can do just that! And all will be good